# Learning a new program! (A designers nightmare)

Tags: gimp, inkscape

Does it have to be so difficult?

I open up GIMP. Wait, what does what?
I open up Inkscape. The controls are so different. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does not work. Ar.AR.ar.

Photoshop, Illustrator and more.

Why does it take ages to learn? Is graphics design so hard?

Help before I pass away (give me some advice please).

Comment: I don't know how anyone can answer this. Any profession takes education be it doctor, lawyer, plumber, accountant, mechanic, painter, designer, etc. You're seeking advice on how to circumvent the education needed to work in a specific field?

Comment: @scott ignore my question. i am just frustrated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is way too broad, but in short:

Some things *are* complex; you cannot have lots of options and possibilities without complexity. Dumbing down results in poor scope.

As for keyboard shortcuts etc, this [**xkcd**](http://xkcd.com/927/) might explain some:

[image: xkcd: Standards]

Comment: true. very true